# Program crashes when assigning value to too many dynamically allocated arrays - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap-memory

I have around +30 dynamically allocated arrays in my program that area each defined like following:

```
int Nx = 240;
int Ny = 240;
double* array = new double(Nx*Ny);
```

I can assign values to 16 of them, but once I reach the 17th, it throws seg fault!

This is the code that throws it, which is totally fine!

```
for (int i = 0; i < Nx*Ny; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

I really have no idea why, I thought of running out of heap, but since I have 4GB of RAM that should be impossible!
I am using MSVS15 and running the program on Windows 10!

Any idea why this happens?
Exact error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00298389 in ecostress.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01D2B000.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: p.s. consider using `std::vector` if it's appropriate for your application.

Comment: You can also use `memset` to zero memory, which is probably faster.

Comment: @Inline: `memset` does not guarantee zeroing anything but an integer array. There is no guarantee `0.´ has a bit-representation of all-zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple typo:

```
double* array = new double(Nx*Ny); // creates a single, initialized double
double* array = new double[Nx*Ny]; // creates an array of doubles
```

Comment: My gooodness! if you have any ideas how many days I spent on this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sorry_I_wont take it easy :)

Answer (score 3):

@Hurkyl answered correctly.

I just wanted to add that if are on C++, then it's better to use vectors:

```
vector<int> array(Nx*Ny);
```

To access the pointer directly you can use `&array[0]`, although there is usually no reason to do this, and you can still do `array[0] = 0`.

The advantage of `vector` and stl generally is that it frees its memory automatically thanks to the destructor.